# Current members in expired membership search results

Tags: civimember, search-results, custom-search

In our database, if expired members 'renew' (or rejoin) after their grace period, on their contact page, on the memberships tab, it shows both an expired membership and a current one. That is correct, I suppose.

If we then do a search for expired members, the rejoined member shows up. That is also correct. We would have to remember to always search for 'expired members - current members' to find those members that have expired and never rejoined.

People are going to forget this. What is the best way to help my client to not forget this ?

Comment: I just wanted to say that I am having the exact same problem as the original poster, and it is beyond frustrating. We have many members that joined, lapsed for several years, and now have recently rejoined. All of those members that rejoined are showing as expired, because they have both 'current' and 'expired' on their profile. The smart group trick does technically work, but I am wondering if there has been any progress finding a cleaner solution. Do you think a patch could be written to fix this? Where could I propose such a job? I will pay money to end this nightmare. I'm thinking along th

Comment: Hi James. This is not an Answer and should have been added as a Comment assuming you have sufficient points to do so. Perhaps you don't. So perhaps you could reframe this as a new question and link to this one. Trying to answer your questions to be of help. 1/ Issues should be lodged at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev. 2/ Paid support can be gained via one of the Partners https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors or by funding the core team. Another work around we have used is to find anyone with 'old' expired memberships and change their status to a new status eg Previous Expired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say how many membership types you have, so I will assume that you only have one.

You could create one smart group (SG1) with criteria Membership status = expired and another (SG2) with membership status of new or current. (And perhaps Grace depending on whether you want those people excluded from your final smart group or not.)

Then you can use the custom search  **Include / Exclude Search** including SG1 and excluding SG2 to define a third smart group that you clearly label as the group to be used when ex-members are required.