# Mutliple memberships search trouble

Tags: civimember, search

Occasionally I have a member that ends up with multiple memberships. I think these may be a result of duplicate merging. So a member may have an expired membership and a current membership.

I have searches/auto groups set up that search for expired members. I select membership status is expired and current member is No. I get the same results no matter the selection.

The search still includes current members who have past expired memberships. In fact the check box for 'Current Member - No' seems to do nothing but add to the search description "AND Is a non-current member".

(we also have multiple membership types, but the problem exists even with the same membership type)

I did find a kludgey solution [HERE](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15799/current-members-in-expired-membership-search-results) that I'll attempt. I have looked at other people asking about this problem, but none seem to describe exactly what does that check box do? Is this a bug?

Oddly the [help page screenshot](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/membership/finding-and-viewing-memberships/) on the documentation seems to be missing that checkbox selection? I'm looking at the  Memberships->Find Members page but I also don't see it on that screenshot of the advanced search page in the documentation either. I have it on both screnes. Perhaps it is database driven and it should have been removed in an upgrade? (or the documentation image is really old?)

I'm using 5.57.1 installed on Joomla.

Answer (score 1):

You are exactly right about what Current Member = No does, it just searches for any contact with a non-current membership, regardless of any other memberships they may have. Here is a [similar recent question](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/42869/find-membership-query) — here's a solution with SearchKit from my answer there:

If you use SearchKit instead, searching for:

- Contacts
- with (required) a Contact Membership with status one of expired or cancelled
- without a Contact Membership with status one of new, pending, current (or using whichever statuses are appropriate)

you should get the results you're looking for.

Unfortunately, I doesn't look like it will be possible to [change Advanced Search.](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/3943)